# Change iframe scrollbar height without changing iframe height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Is there any way to make an iframe's vertical scrollbar shorter than the iframe itself?  For instance have a 500px high iframe with a 450px high scrollbar (but the scrollbar would still fully pan the iframe's content).

(with Javascript, jQuery, or CSS)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [custom scroll bar](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar) with JavaScript.

All the usual caveats apply - usability, etc

> *Hey c'mere grandson, this scroll bar thingo is smaller than the panel, I don't know how to use it. Maybe I'll try another website...*

Answer (score 0):

You can always go for the dumb approach and embed a smaller scrollable frame as part of that iframe (which would not need to be scrollable at all then).